# Part of html file inside php file doesnt appear when executing the code in localhost

Tags: php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a regitration page which includes php,html and css in bootstrap.Here is my php file.

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <!--content-->
  <div class=" container">
    <div class=" register">
      <h1>Register</h1>

      <?php if(isset($_GET[ 'error'])) { echo '<font color="red">'.$_GET[ 'error']. '</font>'; echo '<br><br>'; } if(isset($_GET[ 'ok'])) { echo '<font color="blue">You are successfully Registered..</font>'; echo '<br><br>'; } ?>


      <form action="process_register1.php" method="POST">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 register-bottom-grid">
      <h3>Personal infomation</h3>
      <div>
        <span>Full Name</span>
        <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" name='fnm'>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Username</span>
        <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" name='unm'>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Password</span>
        <input type='password' name='pwd' size="30">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span> Confirm password</span>
        <input type='password' name='cpwd' size="30">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span> Gender</span>
        <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender" id='f'>Female
        <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" id='m'>Male
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>E-mail address</span>
        <input type='mail' name='mail' size="30">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span> No contact</span>
        <input type="text" name='contact' size="30">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span> City</span>
        <select style="width: 195px;" name="city">

          <option>Tirana</option>
          <option>Korca</option>
          <option>Vlora</option>
          <option>Kavaja</option>



        </select>
      </div>


      <input type="submit" value="submit">


    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my header.php file:

```html
<?php session_start(); require( 'config.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Online Shopping</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom Theme files -->
  <!--theme-style-->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <!--//theme-style-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="New Store Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
  <script type="application/x-javascript">
    addEventListener("load", function() {
      setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
    }, false);

    function hideURLbar() {
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }
  </script>
  <!--fonts-->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!--//fonts-->
  <!-- start menu -->
  <link href="css/memenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/memenu.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".memenu").memenu();
    });
  </script>
  <script src="js/simpleCart.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--header-->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="search">
          <form>
            <input type="text" value="Search " onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="header-left">
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION[ 'status'])) { echo '<ul><li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li></ul>'; } else { echo '<ul>
      <li ><a href="login1.php"  >Login</a></li>
      <li><a  href="register.php"  >Register</a></li>

     </ul>'; } ?>

          <div class="cart box_1">
            <a href="checkout.html">
              <h3> <div class="total">
       <span class="simpleCart_total"></span> (<span id="simpleCart_quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> items)</div>
       <img src="images/cart.png" alt=""/></h3>
            </a>
            <p><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_empty">Empty Cart</a>
            </p>

          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="head-top">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1 class="title">Welcome 
       <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['status']))
        {
         echo $_SESSION['unm']; 
        }
        else
        { 
         echo 'Book Store';
        }
       ?>
    </div>
    <div class=" h_menu4">
    <ul class="memenu skyblue">
       <li class="active grid"><a class="color8" href="index1.php">Home</a></li> 
          <li><a class="color1" href="#">Categories</a>
          <div class="mepanel">
                              <div class="row">
         
          <?php
         $query="select * from category ";
                           $res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                          
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
         { 
                                      echo'         <div class="col1">
                              <div class="h_nav">
                             <ul>';
                                  
           echo '<li>
                  <a href="subcat.php?cat='.$row['cat_id'].'&catnm='.$row["cat_nm"].'">'.$row["cat_nm"].'
                  </a>
                 </li>';

            
            
          
                                }
             echo' </ul> 
                            </div>       
                         </div>';





           mysqli_close($conn);
                  ?>

           
      
          
     
       
        
    <li><a class="color6" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul> 
   </div>
    
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>
  </div>

 </div>
```

The problem is when I try to open the files from localhost only the header of the page appears so this is the result:[image]
How is it possible that the form doesnt appear?

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Look in the source code of the page, I bet it is not executing your PHP code? It requires you to run a PHP server.

Comment: Your including the header before the <html> tag, this sure isn't good.

Comment: No error messages just an error in sublime text about missing dependencies.

Comment: What's the content of the header.php file, and if it returns markup shouldn't it be in the body of your HTML doc (`<html>`), not before it? Does it close the `<html>` tag, or exit processing?

Comment: @Sergeon nope the same result

Comment: @xjstratedgebx im uploading the header in the question

Comment: Check your stylsheets and make sure nothing is hidden by CSS styling. Additionally, try adding a few `<br>` tags above the the form. Edit: remove the duplicate tags in the main .php file.

Comment: You can't simply include an entire HTML page like that - the document would end up all messed up with 2 html tags, two head tags etc etc

Comment: How do you open it in your local host (With which url I mean)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that your `header.php` begins a proper html page with doctype, `<html>` etc... but after

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
```

you start your html file again:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
```

Make sure your markup is valid!

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like your header file isn't a header, it's a complete HTML document. It opens the document (`<html>`) and then closes it (`</html>`). So it makes sense that any HTML you put *after* including the header won't get rendered - the browser will render the header and assume the document is complete.

Instead you header file should end where the markup for the header ends. Usually this is the opening tag for the container of your content.

Then when you include the header file, it will contain all the markup up to where your content begins, and in your form's file you can put the code for the form and it'll get rendered next.

In your case, try removing the `</body>` and `</html>` tags from the header file. That will likely work, though your markup will likely need to be updated to make the design coherent. Also, since those are being created by your header, remove the `<html>`, `<head></head>`, and `<body>` tags from your form's file.

You can also create a footer file that you can include after your form content, and it will close the container and the `body` and `html` tags.

### Edit

May have scrolled to the end of the first code block when I saw the `</body></html>`, so you can probably disregard the advice to remove them from the header file - they appear to be there only in my imagination. Removing the opening `<html>`, `<body>`, and `<head>` tags from the from file *should* do the trick however.